# What is the range of the EOD bot?

Tags: battlefield-3

I've recently unlocked the EOD bot, and while playing around with it (and being hopelessly ineffectual with it) I've noticed that after I have driven a certain distance away I will return back to first-person view. Running towards the EOD bot will allow me to take control of it again.

How far can I drive an EOD bot away from me before I lose control of it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I started on an empty server playing Operation Firestorm (conquest large) with a 1 player start, and drove the EOD bot all the way from the US deployment to the RU deployment, and beyond -- to the very edge of the map on the opposite side.

Based on this, I am confident that the **range of the EOD bot is effectively infinite, or at least as large as the very largest Battlefield 3 map so far.**

So, I'm not sure why you're losing control of the bot, but range is not the reason.

Comment: I'll have to go back and have another look then. Perhaps it's time related.

Comment: @Jeff : I'm not sure if this is helpful and informative, or just plain sad! :)  It must of taken an AGE to do that. It's bad enough when you have to run from the deployment to the first flag/mcom...

Comment: @guy science takes work

Comment: @JeffAtwood, I laughed out loud when you told the story on the podcast ([#28](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/se-podcast-28-brent-ozar))! And I completely agree with the point - I hate having to accept answers that are only opinion and you know they don't know the answer for sure.

Comment: @Tom, if you don't like accepting such answers, then don't. Nobody's forcing you to accept any answer.